# ProgressDialog closing onClick

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-asynctask

I start an `AsyncTask` to load a file that takes some time. To inform the user I'm showing a `ProgressDialog`, however if I touch the screen the `ProgressDialog` closes immediately. What could be the cause of this?

```
 public LoadTask(Activity activity, FaceRecognizer recognizer,SecretKey key) {
    this.key = key;     
    this.recognizer = recognizer;       
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.setMessage("Loading the recognizer...");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    recognizer.load(key);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this...

```
public LoadTask(Activity activity, FaceRecognizer recognizer,SecretKey key) {
    this.key = key;     
    this.recognizer = recognizer;       
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
     /////////////////////////////////////////// 
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
           //or////////
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: [`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dialog.setIndeterminate();
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```